# Compiling QtOpenCL with QT5

Tags: opencl, qmake, qt5

Anyone managed to compile library [QtOpenCL](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/opencl) using Qt5 (possibly under Window)?

**edit**: I managed to compile the code by porting it to QT5. I leave here in the question the dirty parts that I would like to replace in my method and describe what I did in the answer.

I was not able to provide the include path to my opencl installation so I

manually modified src/opencl/opencl.pro by adding the line

```
INCLUDEPATH += " *[absolute path to the openCL include folder]* "
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENCL = "*[absolute path to the opencl lib folder]*"
```

manually modified  src/openclgl/openclgl.pro by adding the line

```
INCPATH += " *[absolute path to the openCL include folder]* "
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENCL = "*[absolute path to the opencl lib folder]*"
```

Anyone knows how to fix this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 6):

Here are the changes I had to introduce:

1. Modify the .pro files in order to add the OpenCL library. This is still an open problem for me. How to fix this in a cleaner way?
2. Link the projects (both opencl.pro and openclgl.pro) to the additional required Qt module QtConcurrent:

   QT += concurrent
3. Fix the #include style by removing the packages, e.g. `#include <qtconcurrentrun.h>`  instead of the old `#include
   <QtCore/qtconcurrentrun.h>`
4. Fix qclvector.cpp by replacing qMalloc, qfree, qMemCopy with, respectively, std::malloc, std::free, std::memcpy

   Moreover modify the initialization of ref in the constructor from ref = 1 to ref.store(1);
5. Removing all the macros **QT_LICENSED_MODULE**

This is enough to compile at least QtOpenCL and QtOpenCLGL using QT5

Comment: I would just add that I also had to modify `static void qt_cl_context_notify(...` in `qclcontext.cpp` to `static void CL_CALLBACK qt_cl_context_notify(...` and `static void qt_clgl_context_notify(...` to `static void CL_CALLBACK qt_clgl_context_notify(...` in `qclcontextgl.cpp`